# How to close/stop a .NET application and re-execute it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, excel, shared, vba

My application updates(running a vba script) an excel shared workbook, and since it is shared, there shouldn't be problems when someone else is using the same file at the same time. But for some reason, sometimes it simply freezes, without any error message, just freezes.

Is there a way to programatically make the application  stops/closes automatically when frozen or after some minutes(In normal conditions, this updating process shouldn't take more than 1 minute)?
And, if possible, re-launch the app again automatically after some minutes for at least 5 attempts?
This way would ensure process completes succesfully.

Comment: Have you considered using windows task scheduler (stop when running more than ...)

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this same thing before but because I had an application that would look for updates to it's self on the network and then update it locally. Problem is, you cannot update the exe that is running.

What I did to get around it is to create another program that would wait a second, update the exe, then run the exe again.

Because I did this with a few different apps, I made my "Updater" generic so I could send some command line parameters and it would use those to copy and run.

If you want to try something else, you might be able to accomplish this same thing by creating a BAT file and running it.  I'm not real good on BAT files so I can't help you there. But, it is another way to handle it.